# Can't compile files that don't belong to my project

Tags: android

I Replaced one attribute of  all of my .xml files by a mistake. so I undo all of them . now Android failed to compile the project because of internal files that does not belong to my project . look at this Error for example:

```
Android resource compilation failed
Output:  C:\Users\andrew\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\support-

compat-28.0.0.aar\0f40d142e6b58b7fe15914d4ec5e3dc5\res\layout\notification_action.xml:24: error: duplicate attribute.

Command: C:\Users\andrew\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows.jar\cacb99a92dc25d61ade7acbb3a469d02\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows\aapt2.exe compile --legacy \
        -o \
        C:\Users\andrew\AndroidStudioProjects\clone\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug \
        C:\Users\andrew\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\support-compat-28.0.0.aar\0f40d142e6b58b7fe15914d4ec5e3dc5\res\layout\notification_action.xml
Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows Daemon #3
```

this happened for many .xml in internal files .
my IDE is Android Studio 3.2.1

Comment: Try to clean your project (Build -> Clean project) and then rebuild.

Comment: I got compilation error . It doesn't work!

Comment: check this file `notification_action.xml:24` you got duplicate attribute

Comment: I told all of the xmls have this problem in internal files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happened to me .Delete this file C:\Users\andrew.gradle\caches\transforms-1 form windows and build your project. this should solve your problem .